# Geofire and querying with firebase and Angularfire

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, geofire, angularfire2

In my ionic2 app I need to show a list where the nearest places (bar, restaurant, etc) informations are updated in realTime. As I read on GeoFire doc, I should keep locations and places details data separate in the tree. So I have the following in my firebase :

```
-geoplacesdata
    -placeID1
       -g:"spdxm88qvr"
       -l
         -0: 43.4658582
         -1: 3.7578978000000234
     -placeID2
        -g:"spdxm88qvr"
        -l
          -0: 45.4658582
          -1: 4.7578978000000234

-places_details
     -placeID1
         -rate: 2
         -name: "Place 1"
         -infos:"Free cocktail"

     -placeID2
         -rate: 3
         -name: "Place 2"
         -infos:"Free for kids"
```

When the user load the page I get his position and with GeoFire I'm able to get each placeID near his area. Pretty cool BUT now it becomes very tricky... Now that I got all the places ID, I want to show all details for these places AND subscribe to every updates occurring in the "infos" child of each selected places ID

I tried that :

```
geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key) => {
placesRef.child(key).on("value", (snapshot) => {
var placesDetails = snapshot.val();
// .. and push each places details snapshot in an array named "matches"
this.matches.push(placesDetails);
});
});
```

It works, I get all the places details for the selected placesID BUT as soon as a place is updated (ex: the child "infos" is update) a new key is pushed to the array and I get duplicate informations..

Is there one other solution better than this ?

Comment: Hi Fank, on every question I ask, I see you edit my question but I never get any answer from you... But it seems (I saw other posts) you have some skills on geofire. Maybe you'll be able to help me..

Comment: This is not specifically GeoFire related. The reason why you get duplicate results in your array is that for all changes you `push` new data to the array.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this issue you have to only insert unique items into your array. Whenever a key fires the `key_entered` event you push that data to your array, but you have to check whether or not it is already there.

e.g.

```
if (this.matches.findIndex((x) => x.$key === placesDetails.$key) === -1) {
  this.matches.push(placesDetails)
}
```